# Large meshes in VTK

Tags: c#, vtk

I have a tool that generates screenshots of a combination of STLs. Currently I am trying to create screenshots of a scene that includes a very large STL (650.000 vertices, 1.700.000 faces). However, if I run the tool a couple of times in a row, the large mesh is sometimes shown in the screenshots and sometimes it is not. This seems very random. Using a slightly smaller mesh (350.000 vertices, 700.000 faces), this problem does not occur.

So my question is: is VTK known to have problems with visualizing such large meshes? Is there a setting in a basic rendering pipeline (renderwindow & renderer) that might make the pipeline able to handle larger meshes?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that calculating the normals on such a huge mesh, in order to use Phong shading, was causing the problem.

Disabling the normal calculation for large meshes (e.g. more than 500000 faces) and using flat shading just for these meshes, seems to have solved the problem. The large meshes now consistently show up in every screenshot.

Comment: How did you disble the normals computation?

Comment: They are not calculated by default, so it is just a matter of not using the vtkPolyDataNormals filter.